# Consequences of an Ultra Deep Ocean

Tags: geography, earth, ocean

Edit:
Let’s say the Earth’s sea bottom, worldwide, became deeper by about 600 more meters. What effects would the added pressure have on the Earth’s crust, if any at all?

Comment: As stated in our [help], no "what if X happened?" questions. And even with your attempt of keeping it grounded, you are asking 6 questions.

Comment: A reminder to NOT answer in comment.

Comment: This is a "you can't get there from here" question. Geostatic pressure would cause the crust under the continents to flow into the now-lower ocean crust areas, making the continents sink, putting everything underwater and ruining your deeper oceans. The entire surface of the planet would change dramatically, but even supercomputer modeling would come up with numerous equally probable results.

Comment: @RobertRapplean Ah. I was merely curious as to what would happen if oceans got deeper, but didn’t want to shove 99 sub questions in there. Thank you for this, I wasn’t aware of this probability.